# Populate a dropdown list in php from mysql table

Tags: php

Is it possible to populate a dropdown list in PHP that only shows the 1 column of the data table?

This is my PHP file. This is how I retrieve the rows from the database. All I want is to display just 1 column of the MySQL table into a dropdown list.

```
<?php  // get all sanggunian
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/eLTS/eLTS_lib/libSanggunianManagement.php");
    $strMessage;


    $mySanggunianManager = new SanggunianManager();

    if($mySanggunianManager->getAllSanggunian($strMessage))
    {
        print "<table id='myTable' class='myTable'  border=0 style='font-size:12px;'>";

        print "<tr>";

            foreach($mySanggunianManager->arrHeaders as $strHeader)

                    //print "<th bgcolor='#003f22'>".$strHeader."</th>";
                    print "<br>";
            foreach($mySanggunianManager->arrObjects as $myRow)
            { 
                print "<tr>";
                //print "<select>";
                foreach($myRow as $strHeader=>$strValue )

                    //print "<td id='td' align='center'>".$strValue."</td>";

                    print "<option>";
                    print $strValue;
                    print "</option>";

                    print "</tr>";
            }

        print "</table>";

    }

?>
```

Comment: Is there any other method in this `SanggunianManager()` class, like `getSanggunian()` or similar

Comment: none sir, it's the only method for getting all the Sanggunian members.

Comment: Could you please share that method? And don't call me sir, 'cause maybe I'm younger than you ;)